# TFS non windows users

Tags: version-control

How can I add non windows users to my team foundation server 2012 express edition? We work with an outsourcing company and we would like a set up where TFS express edition is accessed by both teams here and outside. Since the outside developers are not our domain/windows users, I am struggling to add every one onto a project. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: TFS 2012 Express is limited to only 5 named users

Comment: On premise TFS only supports Windows auth (either local or domain), I would suggest you look at using Team Foundation Service (TFS in the cloud) for this project. It's currently free and uses Microsoft live accounts instead.

Comment: +1 @Betty, that's right, I only have one question Betty, why you answer in the comment and if that user want to make your answer as the answer he can't? 

I know we can use comment for clarification or asking little bit about the main question?

Comment: *shrug* probably should have been an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about 2012, but previous versions of TFS could be managed on a Workgroup. You would need to create local accounts for all your users. And even domain users would need to authenticate each time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On premise TFS only supports Windows auth (either local or domain).

I would suggest you look at using Team Foundation Service (TFS in the cloud) for this project. It's currently free and uses Microsoft live accounts instead.

Comment: TF Service is not an option for us. Thank you.

Comment: Then you're stuck with adding windows users, and potentially upgrading to something other than express.

Comment: The cloud version only has English.