# Team Foundation Server 2012 Non Domain User Access

Tags: tfs

I am very new in Team Foundation Server.

I want to create a server at home and i want to use this server from another computer with my developer partner.

The main problem is that, i don't want to create domain users to access team foundation server. I am running an svn server and i want to migrate its data to TFS. Can non domain user (only a dedicated user like in svn server) access TFS from outside of the network?

I installed a Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2012 and Team Foundation Server 2012. I have created a team project, then i want to connect to server from visual studio from another computer and got a standard "server unable to access" error message.

Can anybody write down the solution by step by step?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS non windows users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636487/tfs-non-windows-users)

Comment: As i wrote i am really new in tfs, two sentences does not solve my problem. Before this post I found similar questions, but did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few choices for collaborating in tfs:

**Domain**: This is the easiest to setup, user-wise. All you have to do is be a member of the domain and a member in a team project.

*You have already said that you do not want this option.*

**Workgroup** This requires you setting up the TFS server as a work group and then creating users in that workgroup that represent your team members. You then add them to your tfs team project(s). The pain part comes from you having to make sure that the username and password your team members log in with matches the work group username and password.

*This is probably going to be your best bet unless you want to subscribe to visual studio online.*

**Visual Studio Online** 
This is almost as easy as the domain setup but isn't free. But connecting remotely is a good option. Plus if you are doing any cloud work it integrates nicely.

This link ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) from Microsoft describes various domain \ work group combos. The one I describe above refers to the one where everything is in a workgroup.

> Local user accounts must be created on the Team Foundation server for
>   all users requiring access to the server. Local user accounts must be
>   added to Team Foundation Server server-level and project-level groups
>   so that the users are authorized on the Team Foundation server. When
>   connecting from a Team Foundation client, such as Team Explorer, in
>   the workgroup, the client user account credentials must match those of
>   the server, or the user will be prompted for a user name and password
>   for an account on the Team Foundation Server.

Comment: I know this is a old answer. But Is it still like that ? and is there no way to make a user for TFS without using domain,workgroup locally ?

Comment: Since Microsoft seems to be moving away from on premise TFS I'm going to guess it is still the same.